# How can I redirect to Report Viewer?

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports

I am facing a problem while working with Reports in WPF... I have created an event

```cs
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  try {
    admissionReportViewer.Owner = Window.GetWindow(this);
    if (_admissionNumber != 0) {
      rd.Load(@"C:\\Users\Sohaib Khalid\source\repos\SMS Degree College\Reports\AdmissionForm - Copy.rpt");
      SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
      conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Other"].ConnectionString;
      conn.Open();

      SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SearchStudentInfoAllById", conn);
      sda.SelectCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdmissionNumber", _admissionNumber);
      sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Active", _active);

      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
      sda.Fill(ds, "StudentTable");
      rd.SetDataSource(ds);
      admissionReportViewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = rd;
    }
  }
  catch(Exception err) {
    this.ShowMessageAsync("No data", err.ToString());
    Debug.WriteLine(err.ToString());
  }
```

after this report also load but it again, ask for parameters:
[image]

and also credentials of server login
[image]

Can Anybody tell me why it is again asking for parameters?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I never used ReportViewer in WPF app, but used it a couple of time on ASP.NET

If WPF works in the same way, you're code is wrong:

- The report is using the data source you set up for design it and not the one you're passing to it
- You're storing the parameter value in the data adapter (query) and not in the report parameters

This is why your report ask for both.

I'll share a bit of code for ASP, try to check if it can be the same for WPF or if you have to change it:

```
// Local mode says to use the datasource we are giving to the report
// instead of the one we used to design it
reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local; 

// Set the path of the report file
LocalReport localReport = reportViewer.LocalReport;
localReport.ReportPath = "PATH_OF_YOUR_REPORT";

// Extract data from the DB (remember to insert the parameters in the query)
var dataset = GetDataSet();

// Assign the dataset to the report source (we need a ReportDataSource)
var source = new ReportDataSource();
source.Name = "SOURCE_NAME_USED_IN_THE_REPORT";
source.Value = dataset.Tables["YOUR_TABLE"];

// Add the source to the report
localReport.DataSources.Add(source);

// Create your report parameter (ex: fromDate)  
var paramFromDate = new ReportParameter();
paramDataDa.Name = "fromDate";
paramDataDa.Values.Add(paramFromDate.ToShortDateString());

// Set the report parameters for the report  
localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { fromDate });
```

I hope this can help you but remember, it is for ASP and not for WPF.
So try to adapt it to WPF and see if they work in the same way